# SQL query(SQL server) to convert EST datetime to UTC datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have been trying to convert the EST DateTime field to UTC DateTime format from SQL Server Management Studio

**Found UTC to EST conversion:**

```sql
select CreateDate CreateDate_UTC,
       CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(CreateDate, DATEPART(TZOFFSET,CreateDate AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'))) as CreateDate_EST
from [TABLE]
```

What could it be the query for EST to UTC? And it should also be as in the below format.
**2020-08-10T18:39:35.000Z**

Can someone help?
Tried to update the TIME ZONE with 'UTC', but it did not convert.

Comment: You already know how to switch the timezone, as you show, so you already know how to change it to UTC instead, and worry about formatting in your presentation layer, not the database layer.

Comment: select CreateDate CreateDate_EST,CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(CreateDate, DATEPART(TZOFFSET,CreateDate AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))) as CreateDate_UTC
from [TABLE] 

did not give the correct results

Comment: `AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`. There's no need to fiddle with `SWITCHOFFSET`.

Comment: Should that be in your question? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query

```
select  replace(convert(nvarchar,GETDATE(),120),' ','T') + 'Z'
```

To make milliseconds as part of result, you can use 121 instead of 120

```
select  replace(convert(nvarchar,GETDATE(),121),' ','T') + 'Z'
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Thank you Manpreet, the conversion in the presentation layer worked as a charm. But the EST to UTC is not working right.

Comment: To convert to UTC you have to add time difference. For example:
select  replace(convert(nvarchar,dateadd(hour,5,GETDATE()),121),' ','T') + 'Z'

Comment: Thank you Manpreet. The format has got fixed. Trying to understand if any function could convert EST to UTC taking into consideration the DST too.